# $n^3/2^n$ convergence using squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question is to show that the sequence $n^3/2^n$ converges using the squeeze theorem. I know that $n^3/2^n$  is less than 1 for n>9. But I am not sure how to find an upper bound for this. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use binomial theorem to get $$2^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}$$ and note that each term in the sum on right is non-negative. Therefore $$2^{n}\geq\binom{n} {4}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}$$ We now have $$0\leq\frac{n^{3}}{2^{n}}\leq\frac{24n^{2}}{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}$$ for $n>3$. Applying Squeeze Theorem we get the desired limit as $0$. Therefore the sequence converges. The above technique can be used to prove the more general result that $n^{k} /x^{n} \to 0$ if $x>1$.

Answer (score 4):

*Being unsure whether this asks for the convergence of the sequence $n^32^{-n}$ to $0$ or for the convergence of the series $\sum\limits_nn^32^{-n}$, and the latter being a stronger result than the former, I am solving for the latter.*

The function $$u:x\mapsto3\ln(x)-\tfrac12\ln(2)x$$ is decreasing on $$x>9$$ because $u'(x)$ has the sign of $$6-x\ln2$$ and $$\ln2>\tfrac23$$ Thus, for every $n>9$, $$n^32^{-n}=e^{u(n)}2^{-n/2}\leqslant e^{u(9)}2^{-n/2}$$ and you are done.